# Why is date field form database (yyyy-mm-dd) displaying as dd-mm?

Tags: php, mysql

I have following info.  `$resultsdob` is pulled from mysql database...

$resultsdob = "2018-01-05";

```
$displaydate = date('F j, Y', strtotime($resultsdob));
```

When I echo `$displaydate`, it's showing as: "May 1, 2018".

Why?  I was expecting "January 5, 2018"

Comment: can't reproduce - https://eval.in/931710

Comment: Either your server is time traveling, or you mixed up the date to yyyy-dd-mm, when adding it.

Comment: Might depend on the setting of your locale.  If American, it'll parse month before day; if British day before month.

Comment: Try to echo your $resultsdob

Comment: I think you have your arguments switched. Think about it for a minute and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks for showing me I wasn't going insane. Has to be a mistake somewhere else earlier in the code, so I'll dig in.  Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: I'm getting the right results, given what you posted. *Goblins?*

Answer (score -1):

To make your code explicit (better than implicit 'cause implicit doesn't always work the way you expect) and to isolate yourself from whatever the current locale is set to ...

```
$resultsdob = "2018-01-05";
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $resultsdob);
echo $dt->format('F j, Y');
```